# How to deal with the dot in the request parameter and display json response in restful webservice

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

I am having a problem with either dot parameter in getting the request or displaying the json response in restful ws. If i am gonna fix the other, the other configuration may not work and vice versa. I am using the spring 4.0 and jackson 2.2.3.

I need these two to work. Like i need to make it sure that all the values that are passing to parameters are capture example the decimal point. http://servername.com/mysalary/50.90 i am just getting only the value of 50. and my result would be displayed as json format. Please see my configuration.

1. here is my applicationContext.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
  
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.wom.api.controller" />
 <!-- this is to allow getting the dot in the request. this one is not working fine -->   
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping" id="handlerMapping">
        <property name="useSuffixPatternMatch" value="false"></property>
        <property name="useTrailingSlashMatch" value="false"></property>
 </bean>
 
 
 <mvc:annotation-driven >
    <mvc:message-converters>
     <!-- this will allow the display of json response and running just fine -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="com.wom.api.config.JasonObjectMapper" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
 </mvc:annotation-driven>
 
 <!--  Enable the images, css, an etc. --> 
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
  
 <!-- Load Hibernate related configuration -->
 <import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />
 <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="resources" />
 </bean>
</beans>
```

2. JsonObjectMapper

```html
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

public class JasonObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper{

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 public JasonObjectMapper() {
  System.out.println("Pass Here");
     this.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
             .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.CREATOR, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
             .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.SETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
             .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
             .setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.IS_GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);

     this.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
     }
}
```

3. Controller Class

```html
public class SalesOrderController {

 @Autowired
 SalesOrderService salesorderService;
 
 static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SalesOrderController.class);
 
 /** GET Method **/
 @RequestMapping(value = "/submitsalesorder/{address}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = "Application/json")
 public @ResponseBody JSONArray submitSalesOrderGET(@PathVariable("address") String address) throws Exception{
  
     /** my code goes here **/
  
 }
}
```

4. My pom.xml

```html
<properties>
 <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
 <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
 <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
  </properties>
  <!-- Spring dependency -->    
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
     <version>${spring.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
 </dependency>

<!-- CodeJackson -->
 
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.3</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.3</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.3</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
     <version>1.9.13</version>
 </dependency>
 
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
     <version>1.9.13</version>
 </dependency>
```

Please help. I am taking too much time with this. :-(

Answer (score 0):

In your request mapping, tell spring to take everything :

```
"/submitsalesorder/{address:.+}"
```

From SpringFramework documentation [Web MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

> The @RequestMapping annotation supports the use of regular expressions
>   in URI template variables. The syntax is {varName:regex} where the
>   first part defines the variable name and the second - the regular
>   expression.For example:
>
> ```
> @RequestMapping("/spring-web/{symbolicName:[a-z-]}-{version:\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d}{extension:\\.[a-z]}")
>     public void handle(@PathVariable String version, @PathVariable String extension) {
>         // ...
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Hi Vyncent..thank you for the answer but i am afraid I cant apply it to my request mapping. because the one with decimal is the array parameter.  "/submitsalesorder/{address}/{salesorderdate}/{paymentmethod}/{contactno}/{note}/{userid}/{arrayparameter}"              where     arrayparameter = "accountnumber, price[with decimal], unit"

Comment: Could you provide an example for the URL with parameters ?

Comment: --- servername/submitsalesorder/makati phil/05052015/credit card/092752356/testing/josuatan/0101345,58.90,60,&0101346,68.20,3;

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved using the suggested solution for "/submitsalesorder/{address:.+}"